# changing swappiness - permission denied

Tags: linux, swappiness

I use "echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness" to set swappiness but even if I'm root i've got access denied. Do you know what should I do to unlock it ?

Comment: It may happen that even if SELinux status is disabled, one would get permission denied issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect SELinux. Try *getenforce* and if it returns *enforcing*, you can temporarily disable SELinux with *setenforce 0*. For permanent disablement see /etc/selinux/config.

Before disabling SELinux you may try *sysctl -w vm.swappiness=0*.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check if [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux) is active. It imposes restrictions even on `root`.

The commmand `sestatus` will tell you if SELinux is active.